# Is working together possible when using Team Foundation Server?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

If one chooses to "prevent other users from checking out and checking in" from Team Foundation Server:

1. Can anyone reach the code?
2. Is there any way to work from another user's computer?
3. How about shelving?

Comment: Do you mean the shelving you put your books on? Can you not use RDP or similar remote desktop solution to work on anothers machine?

Comment: What do you mean by "can anyone reach the code"?

Comment: means that can anyone use the code..

Answer (score 2):

I would interpret that sort of lock as meaning that someone is going to do something so destructive that it is in your interests to not have an edited copy when that happens. If you think it is a mistake, talk to the person who locked the file.

An option, if you really want to do this, is to remove the readonly attribute on the file yourself (in Windows Explorer or through a shell) and edit the file. That is a good way to cause yourself trouble, though, if the file is going to be changed substantially by the person that locked it. Also, you will need to later mark it as checked out in TFS to actually check it in.

I do not think you will be able to shelve the file (unless you follow the option below) since you will not be able to check it out for edit.

One last option is that you could branch the file, work on the branch, and then merge it back in later. Once again, though, that may be difficult if the edits by the person locking the file are going to be extensive.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understood all of your questions, but I'll give it a chance:

1. If by reach you mean, get latest version and read, yes they could. But they wouldn't be able to change the code while it's locked unless they circumvent Visual Studio and change the read-only attribute of the with the command-prompt, Windows Explorer etc.
2. Visual Studio and TFS 2010 introduces the concept of permissions on workspaces. A workspace now can be private (the old behavior), public limited or public. **Using a public workspace, on could edit the files in the workspace of another person.** See [tf workspace /permission](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y901w7se.aspx) for more information.
3. You can shelve anything that is in your workspace regardless of locks on anybody's workspaces.

Comment: For #3 you shouldn't be able to shelve something that you can't check out.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to the permission values for TFS

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252587.aspx

This should answer your questions